# Android Realm query distinct foreign keys

Tags: android, realm

I am using `Realm` with my Android application and I have 2 models: `Transaction` and `Category`. Each transaction has a foreign key to Category. I want to do a query where I find all Categories that have a foreign key reference.

```
public class Transaction extends RealmObject:
    public Category category;
    ... other fields
```

I tried this to get the unique list of Transactions with different Categories:

```
RealmResults<Transaction> transactions = 
            realm.where(Transaction.class).distinct("category");
```

but it doesn't work because I would need to index it and Realm does not support foreign key indexes

Comment: does your category have a primary key?

Comment: Yes. Both Transaction and Category have their own primary key.

Comment: In Realm 3.0.0, I think `distinct("category.id")` should work.

Comment: .... Actually, distinct across links is still not supported. Consider adding `categoryId` to Transaction, next to `category` as a field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow my [guide for Realm schema design in case of uni-directional links](https://hackernoon.com/designing-the-schema-of-realm-effectively-and-other-realm-tips-feb76c5b6072#.fxmu0jq9u), as in, you do

```
public class Transaction extends RealmObject:
    public Category category;

    @Index
    public long categoryId;
    ... other fields
```

And

```
public class Category extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    public long id;

    ...
```

Then you can do

```
RealmResults<Transaction> transactions = 
        realm.where(Transaction.class).distinct("categoryId");
```